# jQuery - disable checkboxes based on firstly clicked checked data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of check boxes. I need to disable all other check boxes with a different data-groupid and leave the check boxes with the same data-groupid enabled. When the user unchecks all the check boxes, all the check boxes become available again. Here's a snip of my HTML. The group ID could be any number and is generated dynamically.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="2">
<input type="checkbox" value="6" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="7" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="4">
<input type="checkbox" value="8" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="9" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="10" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="6">
<input type="checkbox" value="11" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="6">
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="6">
<input type="checkbox" value="13" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="14" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="15" name="mergeTicked[]"  class="pickSheetCheck" data-groupid="3">
```

And here's how far i've got with the jQuery. I know it errors but i'm nearly there I think. I also need to enable all the check boxes when they are all unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $inputs = $(".pickSheetCheck");
function checkInput(thisObj){
var datagrp = thisObj.attr("data-groupid");
$(input:not[data-groupid=datagrp]).attr("disabled", true);


alert(datagrp);

}


$inputs.change(function() {
    checkInput($(this));
});
});
```

It seems simple enough what I'm trying to do but I've been at this for a while!

**EDIT:**

I've got it working however I could do with some help 'resetting' when no check boxes are selected

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $inputs = $(".pickSheetCheck");
function checkInput(thisObj){
var datagrp = thisObj.attr("data-groupid");

$( ".pickSheetCheck" ).not( '[data-groupid="'+datagrp+'"]' ).attr("disabled", true);
}
$inputs.change(function() {
    checkInput($(this));
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the checkboxes you could just count the checked boxes and if there's none, enable all.

```
if ($('.pickSheetCheck:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
  $inputs.attr('disabled', false);
} else {
  $( ".pickSheetCheck" ).not( '[data-groupid="'+datagrp+'"]' ).attr("disabled", true);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/fisojunuqo/edit?js,output).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up some code to the `change` event of all the check boxes.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    var this_dataid = $(this).attr('data-groupid');
    var this_checked = $(this).is(':checked');

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

    if ( $(this).attr('data-groupid') == this_dataid ) {

        $(this).prop('checked', this_checked);

    }else{

        $(this).prop('checked', false);

    }

  });

});
```

here is [a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/08kmLgqm/4/)

You can use jQuery to check the check status and the custom `data-groupid` value of the element that was clicked.  That I use the jQuery's `each` function to loop through all the other `input` elements and set the check status accordingly using `prop`.

https://api.jquery.com/